# Is it necessary to push your commit files from a new branch?

Tags: git, github

I created a new branch to work on so I can improve my app and therefore made a new branch. As you all know, you need to commit your changes to your new branch so it won't affect your main branch.

My question is do you have to push your commits from your new branch at all and if you do push your commits what will it do? Also, why would you want to push your commits from your new branch?

Comment: To greatly simplify things: git commit will store your changes to a local repository, where only you can see them. git push will transfer all stored changes from your local to a remote repo, where others can see them. You would push the changes so that others can contribute/help you with your work.

Comment: Hey @SiKing. Thanks for your help. So just to be sure I understand this correctly. If I only commit any changes I'm the only one that is able to see them and it will not show on my GitHub repo and it will only be shown in my local remote repo? And if I do push my commits they would show publically in my GitHub repo?

Comment: Your use of terminology is still confusing. "my local remote repo" is questionable; a repo is either local or remote, but not both. But it sounds as if you have the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to do *anything*.

You are working with a Git repository on your computer (called the "local"). The notion "push" implies that you have some *other* Git repository in some *other* location (called the "remote") that you want to keep synchronized with the one on your computer; GitHub is an example of another location of that sort.

You might have a remote in order to share your code with others, or simply as a way of backing up your work to another machine in case your machine has an issue. But if neither of those things is the case, then you probably have to reason to have a remote, so there is nothing to push to and you shouldn't worry about it.